# Perform a reboot when custom swap file almost full

Tags: linux, cron, swap

Im pretty new to linux, and im trying to figure out a way to reboot my server if the swapfile i created and assigned into the system is almost full. So lets say  that i have a 10gb swapfile, and i want to perform a reboot everytime it reaches 9.5gb usage.

Is it possible? all i know is that swapfile -s shows up how much space is taken, and that i would need to add something to my crontab, so as you can see nott much... i would apreciate a very precise answer, and if possible with a breif explanation so i can understand what im doing.

Thanks
Kind regards

Comment: My very precise answer is that you have a wish here posing as a question.

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work? You should be able to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using SO/Google.

Comment: What did i try: Nothing, i dont know where to start with. The operating system is Ubuntu 20.04, Thanks for your precise answer, Will see if others can give a more precise one, or at least help in any way.

Comment: "or at least help in any way." I'm sorry that I'm trying to explain that you probably won't get an answer on a question this broad.

Comment: I wasnt judging your comment, yours was ok, it was roadowl. Would you please help me rephrase or conduct my question please?

Comment: You could start by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) thats shows your own attempts (even if they failed) and a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on the issue you've found.

Answer (score 1):

The way to acomplish above would be to create a script, i named it swap.sh with the following content:

```
 #!/bin/bash

free=`free -mt | grep Total | awk '{print $4}'`

if [ $free -lt 256 ]; then
        sudo systemctl --no-wall reboot
fi
```

Which basically will check if the total memory is bellow 256mb, then it will perform a reboot.

Then simply go into crontab and add a line to launch the script every 5 minutes or whatever you consider.